# handle model structure changes in javascript frontend

Tags: javascript

How can I handle changes in the dto I am getting from the server when I am using javascript.
If I cant use compilation,so what are my options?
for example ,
If I have this structure:

```
Person {int:Age,string:Name}
```

and someday the server will send me

`Person {int:MyAge,string:MyName}`

In C# the compilation will warn me about it, but if I am working in javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're delivering JSON to the JavaScript the response from your backend should look like this.

```
{
    'person': {
        'age': PersonInstance.Age / PersonInstance.MyAge,
        'name': PersonInstance.Name / PersonInstance.MyName
    }
}
```

Thus ensuring that as long as the keys `age` and `name` is always the same your JavaScript will never need to know what property of your PersonInstance is used.